# Ruby: undefined method `_run_suite' for class `Test::Unit::Runner'

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run this code with a command-line command ruby unit_test.rb:

```
# unit_test.rb
require 'test/unit'
class TestWordsFromString < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_smth
    assert_equal([], [])
  end
end
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
From:
  /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  unit_tests.rb:1:in `<main>'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>'
/Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:676:in `<class:Runner>': undefined method `_run_suite' for class `Test::Unit::Runner' (NameError)
    from /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:261:in `<module:Unit>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:15:in `<module:Test>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from unit_tests.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

What I tried:
1. Adding `require 'minitest/autorun'` 
2. Running the tests with `bundle exec ruby unit_tests.rb` command instead. 
3. Installing gem 'minitest'

Neither of these solutions worked. Maybe I'm just running the tests wrong? I'm working though the book "Programming Ruby".

Answer (score 2):

The answer was simple:

> Ruby 1.9.x bundles minitest not Test::Unit. Test::Unit bundled in Ruby
>   1.8.x had not been improved but unbundled Test::Unit (test-unit) is improved actively.

Just installed Ruby 1.9 to the RVM and everything works fine now!

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the sample problem. Thanks for your post and it pointed me to the right direction. You can keep using ruby 1.9.x by just switching to use minitest.

1. Change `require 'test/unit'` to `require 'minitest/autorun'`
2. Change `class TestWordsFromString < Test::Unit::TestCase` to `class TestWordsFromString < Minitest::Test`

Just need to inherit your test from minitest instead of TestUnit.

Comment: This is a great start to converting test suites.  There are also some matcher changes.  For anyone getting an error about `assert_not_equal`, change it to `refute_equal`.  Minitest renamed `assert_not_x` matchers to `refute_x`.